# Non-bipartite graph with symmetric adjacency spectrum?

Tags: graph-theory, linear-algebra

In "Spectra of Graphs" by Brouwer and Haemers they gives examples of 2 graphs whose Laplace spectrums are the same, but only one of which is bipartite. I am wondering if there is a similar example for the adjacency spectrum:

1) What's an example of a non-bipartite graph whose adjacency spectrum is still symmetric about 0?

2) Are there graphs $G_1, G_2$ such that they have the same adjacency spectrum but only one of which is bipartite?

Answer (score 1):

A graph is bipartite iff its adjacency spectrum is symmetric about $0$.  See [Bipartite Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph). So the bipartiteness of a graph is completely determined by its spectrum and there are no such examples.